# Captcha with custom PHPBB login page

Tags: php, captcha, phpbb

I'm trying to make a captcha popup on the screen when you fail to enter your password wrong too many times but not sure how to go about it. I've found quite a few pages about this but they all involve using a template and none of those pages explain what I have to put into my form.

Here's what I got so far.

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
    global $auth, $db, $cache, $config, $user, $phpbb_root_path, $phpEx, $template;
    $phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : '../main/';
    $phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

    $user->session_begin();
    $auth->acl($user->data);

    $remember = $remember==1?true:false;
    $result = $auth->login($username, $password, $remember);

    if ($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS){
        return "LOGIN_SUCCESS";
        //Launch captcha
    }else{
        if($result['status']==LOGIN_ERROR_ATTEMPTS){
            return "LOGIN_ERROR_ATTEMPTS";
        }
        if($result['status'] == LOGIN_ERROR_EXTERNAL_AUTH){
            return "No profile exists.";
        }elseif($result['status'] == LOGIN_BREAK){
            return "Failed to create session.";
        }elseif($result['status'] == LOGIN_ERROR_PASSWORD){
            return "Incorrect Password.";
        }elseif($result['status'] == LOGIN_ERROR_USERNAME){
            return "Invalid Username.";
        }elseif($result['status'] == LOGIN_ERROR_PASSWORD_CONVERT){
            return "Internal error, failed to convert password.";
        }elseif($result['status'] == LOGIN_ERROR_ACTIVE){
            return "User is inactive.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: On a side note, why not use switch, case and break instead of so many elseif's?

Comment: Yeah, I was planning too change that but this captcha is a bigger issue for me right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
global $auth, $db, $cache, $config, $user, $phpbb_root_path, $phpEx, $template;
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
if (!class_exists('phpbb_captcha_factory'))
{
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/captcha/captcha_factory.' . $phpEx);
}
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$remember = isset($_POST['remember']) ? $_POST['remember'] : '' ;
$remember = $remember==1?true:false;
$result = $auth->login($username, $password, $remember);
$err = '';

    switch ($result['status'])
    {
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            $err .= 'Welcome ' . $user->data['username'];
        break;

        case LOGIN_ERROR_EXTERNAL_AUTH:
            $err .= 'No profile exists';
        break;

        case LOGIN_ERROR_ATTEMPTS:
            $err .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=your_public_key">' . "/n"
            . '</script>' . "/n"
            . '<noscript>' . "/n"
            . '<iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=your_public_key" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>' . "/n"
            . '<textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">' . "/n"
            . ' </textarea>' . "/n"
            . ' <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge">' . "/n"
            . '</noscript>';
            $err .= 'LOGIN_ERROR_ATTEMPTS';
        break;

        case LOGIN_ERROR_PASSWORD_CONVERT:
            $err .= 'Internal error, failed to convert password.';
        break;

        case LOGIN_BREAK:
            $err .= "Failed to create session.";
        break;

        case LOGIN_ERROR_PASSWORD:
            $err .= "Incorrect Password.";
        break;

        case LOGIN_ERROR_USERNAME:
            $err .= "Invalid Username.";
        break;

        case LOGIN_ERROR_ACTIVE:
            $err .= "User is inactive.";
        break;
    }
return $err;
```

Comment: I had someone like that before, but $captcha->get_template() will return false or 'captcha_default.html' not sure how I could implement that into my form? I'm not even sure what that 'captcha_default.html' page is. What do I name the input field for it? That code there doesn't handle a input for the captcha text.

Comment: The only way to include the captcha is use a phpbb template or you could always use your own captcha or there are other ways to accomplish the same as your doing shown below.
use `login_box(request_var('redirect', "index.$phpEx"));`
or make a post to `../main/ucp.php?mode=login&redirect=myredirect`